# Populate 3 Custom Fields on Sales Order Header

Tags: suitescript2.0

Wondering if someone could assist with the code below.  This was a script I had copied over from an old instance of Netsuite we had and I was hoping to get it to work.  The goal is to calculate the total KG's, LB's and master cartons needed for an order by cycling through the sublist of items on a sales order.

The problem is that the script has been deployed and it's not populating the 3 custom fields of the sales order record.
-custbody_summary_carton_qty
-custbody_summary_weight
-custbody_summary_weight_lbs

```
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define(['N/https', 'N/record', 'N/search'], function (https, record, search) {

    var COMPANY_DEFAULT_SHIPPING_ID = 5605;
    var COMPANY_DEFAULT_SHIPPING_LABEL = '004UPS_BMI';

    function calculateSummaryInfo(rec) {
        var totalCartons = 0,
            totalKg = 0,
            totalLb = 0
        if (rec.getLineCount('item') != 0) {
            var itemIds = ["internalid", "anyof"]

            for (var i = 0; i < rec.getLineCount('item'); i++) {
                var item = rec.getSublistValue('item', 'item', i)
                if (itemIds.indexOf(item) == -1)
                    itemIds.push(item)
            }
            var results = searchItems(itemIds)

            for (var i = 0; i < rec.getLineCount('item'); i++) {

                var item = rec.getSublistValue('item', 'item', i)
                if (results.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                    var qty = parseInt(rec.getSublistValue('item', 'quantity', i)),
                        itemCartQty = parseInt(results[item].cartonQty),
                        itemKg = parseFloat(results[item].weightKg),
                        itemLb = parseFloat(results[item].weightLb)
                    if (qty / itemCartQty <= Math.round(qty / itemCartQty)) {
                        totalCartons += Math.round(qty / itemCartQty)

                    } else {
                        totalCartons += Math.round(qty / itemCartQty) + 1
                    }
                    totalKg += qty / itemCartQty * itemKg
                    totalLb += qty / itemCartQty * itemLb
                }
            }
        }
        rec.setValue('custbody_summary_carton_qty', totalCartons, true)
        rec.setValue('custbody_summary_weight', totalKg.toFixed(2), true)
        rec.setValue('custbody_summary_weight_lbs', totalLb.toFixed(2), true)
    }})

    function searchItems(ids) {
        var results = {}
        var inventoryitemSearchObj = search.create({
            type: "inventoryitem",
            filters:
                [
                    ["type", "anyof", "InvtPart"],
                    "AND",
                    ids
                ],
            columns:
                [
                    search.createColumn({ name: "custitem_master_carton_weight_kg", label: "Master Carton Net Weight (kg)" }),
                    search.createColumn({ name: "custitem_master_carton_weight_lb", label: "Master Carton Net Weight (lb)" }),
                    search.createColumn({ name: "custitem_inner_carton_quantity_eaches", label: "Master Carton QTY" }),
                    search.createColumn({ name: "internalid", label: "Internal ID" })
                ]
        });
        inventoryitemSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {
            results[result.getValue('internalid')] = {}
            results[result.getValue('internalid')].weightKg = result.getValue('custitem_master_carton_weight_kg')
            results[result.getValue('internalid')].weightLb = result.getValue('custitem_master_carton_weight_lb')
            results[result.getValue('internalid')].cartonQty = result.getValue('custitem_inner_carton_quantity_eaches')
            return true;
        });
        return results
    }
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is

Comment: Sorry pretty dopey of me.  The problem is that the script has been deployed and it's not populating the 3 custom fields of the sales order record.

-custbody_summary_carton_qty
-custbody_summary_weight
-custbody_summary_weight_lbs

Answer (score 0):

What is your entry point for the user event script?  UE scripts have to have an entry point.  how are you calling the functions in your code?

when you are loading your item record, are you using the correct type?